# How to split a file on a floppy disk without installing any software in DOS?

Tags: command-line, floppy, disk-operating-system

I want to split a 2.6 MB file on a floppy disk. Is there a way that I can use a DOS command to help me in a pure dos environment. (no applications are allowed to install)

Answer (score 2):

There is no command on the plain dos to do that. You have to use an application.

You have 2 options:

- You can run rar or pkzip from a floppy disk and use it to split the file. Technically you aren't installing anything.
- Use qbasic and write a program to do that (qbasic is part of dos)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.kkuzba.com/links/qbsrc/qbsrc.html) is a site that has the source of a couple of useful qbasic programs for you (concat.bas and splitter.bas).